# Not an answer flagged for moderator

Tags: discussion, plagiarism

This question has an open bounty:
*[SQL get ip address of user calling stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47395311/sql-get-ip-address-of-user-calling-stored-procedure)*

And a user copied the answer from *https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941136/2723943* and pasted it as an answer which is copied from *[How to get the client IP address from SQL Server 2008 itself?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941074/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-from-sql-server-2008-itself)*

I raised a flag for moderator attention which is pending. As well I downvoted the answer. But this answer got 2 upvotes also.

My question is, in this case, is a moderator flag right or should I use some other action?

Comment: You are correct to flag it. Just give us some time to process the queue, there are *lots* of flags for us to handle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your flag is in the queue - if you're right, the answer will be deleted (and with it, any reputation the user earned/lost).

The other upvotes are probably from people who think the answer is good and didn't know the answer was copied from some other place.